# How to customize the bibliography?

Tags: bibliographies

I have the following minimal example which is texed with pdfLaTeX.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

The reference is \cite{test1}.

\begin{thebibliography}{999}
\bibitem{test1} text1
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Now I want to show "text1" instead of "[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jzpfn.png)" in the pdf. How can I achieve this?

Furthermore, I would like to have no numbering ("[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jzpfn.png),..") in the Bibliography chapter of the pdf.
Are there any commands?

[image]

Comment: Please always provide a full compilable but minimal document for your questions. Like this, it is much more work on our side and just a guessing around. Also, please just do one question per post. The last two topics a described a lot on this homepage. Please bother the search function.

Comment: Please provide a full MWE rather than just code snippets. It looks like you're building the bibliography "by hand," i.e., one `\bibitem` at a time. If that's the case, why bother to provide a `\bibliographystyle` instruction (which is used by BibTeX, which you don't seem to be using)? Finally, how is `\cite{text}` supposed to work without an entry named "text"? (You have one called "test1"...) The name of the bibliography section -- "References", "Bibliography", etc -- is determined by the document class. Without this piece of information it's going to be difficult to provide useful advice.

Comment: @lockstep - Since the code snippets don't indicate an actual use of BibTeX, I would have deleted that tag too...

Comment: @Mico `\bibliographystyle{alpha}` sounds like BibTeX for me.

Comment: okay, I made a minimal example. The name "References" indeed is specified in documentclass, apparently.

Comment: @lockstep - now that this instruction has been dropped from the modified MWE, I think I'll do some further retagging.

Comment: Why are you doing everything by hand? Use `biblatex` with `biber` and an `authoryear`-style (i guess).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like you're creating the bibliography by yourself, one `\bibitem` at a time, *without* BibTeX or biblatex.

If this impression is correct, you need to provide

- all formatted information for the bibliographic entry *after* the citation key
- the citation-related information in square brackets in between `\bibitem` and the citation key. (If there's no material in brackets, LaTeX will implement the default, i.e., numerical, citation callout style.)

If, as I suggest, you also load the `natbib` package, the command `\citet{test1}` will produce the callout `Carlson (2015)`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}  % a citation management package
\begin{document}
These claims are due to \citet{test1}.
\begin{thebibliography}{999}
\bibitem[Carlson(2015)]{test1} Carlson, C., 2015, ``Some title,'' \emph{Random Thoughts Journal} 1, pp. 1--100.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```